# Problem with an exercise in From Real to Complex Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I got a copy of From Real to Complex Analysis for my birthday and I am using it for self-study. I am now at the point where evaluations of different integrals are being made using the earlier-developed properties of integrals. There is an exercise that goes as follows:

Let $f$ be a Riemann-integrable function on $[a,b]$ and suppose that, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $r\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$, real numbers $\xi_r^{(n)}$ are chosen such that
$$a+(r-1)(b-a)/n\leq\xi_r^{(n)}\leq a+r(b-a)/n.$$
Prove that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{r=1}^nf(\xi_r^{(n)})=(b-a)^{-1}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx.$$

I have managed to prove this, but I am stuck on the next exercise:

Using the result of the preceding exercise, show that
$$\int_0^{\pi}\sin x\,dx=2.$$

I know that this is equivalent to showing that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{r=1}^nf(\xi_r^{(n)})=\frac{2}{\pi}$$ for all $\xi_r^{(n)}$ such that $(r-1)\pi/n\leq\xi_r^{(n)}\leq r\pi/n$, and I had the idea to show that, when each $\xi_r^{(n)}$ is chosen such that $f(\xi_r^{(n)})=\sup\{f(x):x\in[(r-1)\pi/n,r\pi/n]\}$, thereby maximising the value of the sum, the limit still equals $2/\pi$, and the same for when $f(\xi_r^{(n)})=\inf\{f(x):x\in[(r-1)\pi/n,r\pi/n]\}$, as each other selection of each $\xi_r^{(n)}$ places the sum between the minimum and maximum, both of which tend to $2/\pi$. Since $\sin x$ is non-decreasing on $[0,\pi/2]$ and non-increasing on $[\pi/2,\pi]$, formulae for the maximum and minimum sums can be quite easily generated, and I did so (for odd $n$ - the process is the same for even $n$ but since you know the limit exists due to the continuity, and therefore Riemann-integrability, of $\sin x$, you don't need to make formulae for even $n$):
$$\mathrm{max:}\,\frac{1}{n}\left[1+\sum\limits_{r=1}^{(n-1)/2}\sin\frac{r\pi}{n}+\sum\limits_{r=(n+3)/2}^n\sin\frac{(r-1)\pi}{n}\right].$$
$$\mathrm{min:}\,\frac{1}{n}\left[\sin\frac{(n+1)\pi}{2n}+\sum\limits_{r=1}^{(n-1)/2}\sin\frac{(r-1)\pi}{n}+\sum\limits_{r=(n+3)/2}^n\sin\frac{r\pi}{n}\right].$$
Since $\sin x$ is Riemann-integrable, proving that the maximum is greater than or equal to $2/\pi$ for all $n$ and that the minimum is less than or equal to $2/\pi$ for all $n$ suffices in proving that the limit equals $2/\pi$, however it is not obvious to me how I should go about proving that this is true. Have I gone wrong anywhere? Any help would be greatly appreciated.